# create joint prob distribution or empirical relation for two variables

Tags: distributions, correlation, computational-statistics, joint-distribution

There are two variables, X1 and X2. The experimental study shows that they are highly correlated. Are there any reliable ways to create an empirical mapping(or equation) between X1 and X2. Assuming there have enough data points for X1 and X2, what are the ways to create joint probability distribution for X1 and X2?